# Mapkit - Always show compass

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit

How do I make my compass, in mapkit, always visible?

In my map it's only visible when I drag the map. But I'd like to make it always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you triad something like that ?

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading];
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked:   map.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.followWithHeading, animated: true)

Comment: Actually, in doesn't appeart when the app launchs. Only when I drag.... why is that? I placed it on viewdidload